# How to avoid false clicks activate unnecessarily function mouseup

Tags: jquery

What solution can I find to prevent unnecessarily clicks activate function mouseup.
here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/c6ABa/6/)

Comment: You want to prevent document.mouseup on clicking on tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('tr').click(function() {
    if($('#input1').hasClass('active')){
        return false;
    }
     $('#span1').hide();

        $('#input1').show().addClass('active');

    });
```

Answer (score 2):

try `stopPropagation()`:

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```
$('tr').click(function(e) {
    $('#span1').hide();
    $('#input1').show();
    e.stopPropagation()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c6ABa/7/

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the element on first mouseup. 
Then do make a check using if hasClass('...').
if the class exists make a return false

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but I don't know how to do that , can you give me plz more details thx